# Why does PlaceAutoCompleteFragment not initiate onPlaceSelected Callback when a place is selected?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I select a place in AutoCompleteFragment in my dummy app, that does not but select a place and print its name in logcat, then the callback OnPlaceSelected does not get called and nothing happens.tem

I tried to place google's code here but still facing the same problem. I tried to decrease the API version from 28 to 25 but that was unyielding.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static final String TAG = "GoogleMaps";
private GoogleMap mMap;
PlaceAutocompleteFragment placeAutoComplete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


}

}
```

The expected result should be that the place i selected must get printed in logcat. Please help.

Comment: Any one please help here.

Comment: Did you get solution for it because i am also getting same hassle.